# Mind is a fire not a vessel

Tags: meaning, phrases, american-english, british-english, metaphors

"Mind is not a vessel to be filled but a fire to be kindled."
What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

"**The** mind is not a vessel to be filled but a fire to be kindled." - [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch).
It means that when teaching, (a child for example), don't just try and fill the brain with facts and knowledge.  If you can inspire someone to be excited or enthusiastic (create a spark inside them), they will love learning about their new favourite subject.

Comment: +1 for the Plutarch source

Comment: +1 " . . . if you give a man a fish he is hungry again in an hour. If you teach him to catch a fish you do him a good turn." ([*Mrs. Dymond*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) by Anne Isabella Thackeray Ritchie)

Answer (score 1):

It contrasts two metaphors for *mind*: a container, or a fire.

A container can be empty or full, but it is passive; someone else does the filling/emptying. So a teacher can teach a student something, and that fills it. No action required (or even possible) by the student.

A fire is an active agent. You start it, and then it does the work by itself. So a teacher lays the groundwork, but the student then does the processing actively. This will take the student beyond what the teacher has provided.

The proverb advocates the learning/developing of the mind as an active process that just needs to be started, rather than being a passive receptacle of wisdom.

Update: for the *mind as a vessel*, compare the [Nuremberg Funnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Funnel).

Comment: So a fire bucket would be a mixed metaphor? / The use of anarthrous 'mind' here is interesting; I'm not sure it works when paired with 'a vessel ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not sure; but it's a filled bucket to extinguish fires... Which in some cultures probably would be seen as appropriate.